# Simultaneous use of yaml and database to store translations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, internationalization

I'm currently using i18n.
I'm thinking about using both YAML and DB for translations because required workflow is next: developer creates default translation in yaml file and some admin users change them.
I see next solution: somehow merge both translation with priority to DB version.
The problem is how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is next: I18n can manage chains. You need to create `config/initializers/i18n_backend.rb` file and put (here is Redis for example):

```rb
I18n.backend = I18n::Backend::Chain.new(I18n::Backend::KeyValue.new(Redis.new), I18n.backend)
```

More info - http://railscasts.com/episodes/256-i18n-backends

Answer (score 2):

One of the workarounds can be importing / merging one into another. Turn on file-based translations by default in development environment and db-based in production and import translation files into database on deployment script (capistrano, etc).